# Proxy Pass and Document root on the same level on apache server

Tags: apache, reverse-proxy, angular-universal, proxypass, document-root

I have an Angular application running on localhost:3000/app1 and I too have html pages on root level like:

site.com/page1 and site.com/page2

Now I want my site.com to be an angular application which will ProxyPass to localhost like

ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000

but by this configuration I an not able to access site.com/page1 and site.com/page2

**Note : Please help me on server configuration part I am not much into it.**

I tried for exclusion (!) for proxy pass but that did'nt worked out.

example:
ProxyPass / !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:3001/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3001/
Alias / /var/www/html/

Comment: This would be better asked on serverfault

Answer (score 0):

You could point apply the proxying to a notional path (`ProxyPass /external http://localhost:3000`) then either route requests here via the 404 handler or by rewriting with a condition that there is no local file. These are ugly hacks. There is no good solution other than tidying up your file paths to align the component services with the directory hierarchy.